# How to bind a widget with my class?

Tags: c++, qt

I created a class called `MyButton` that inherits `QPushButton`. Form (mainwindow.ui) has the widget `pushButton`. How to bind `pushButton` with `MyButton` in Qt Creator to allow to reimplement paintEvent()?

Comment: You mean in the QtDesigner? Which Qt and QtCreator are you using?

Comment: Yes. I use Qt 5.2 with Qt Creator 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following screenshot from the official documentation demonstrates how to promote your custom class:

[image]

As per [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdesigner/designer-using-custom-widgets.html):

> If some forms must be designed, but certain custom widgets are unavailble to the designer, we can substitute similar widgets to represent the missing widgets. For example, we might represent instances of a custom push button class, MyPushButton, with instances of QPushButton and promote these to MyPushButton so that uic generates suitable code for this missing class.

Then reading further on:

> To add a placeholder, select an object of a suitable base class and choose Promote to ... from the form's context menu. After entering the class name and header file in the lower part of the dialog, choose Add. The placeholder class will now appear along with the base class in the upper list. Click the Promote button to accept this choice.
>
> Now, when the form's context menu is opened over objects of the base class, the placeholder class will appear in the Promote to submenu, allowing for convenient promotion of objects to that class.
>
> A promoted widget can be reverted to its base class by choosing Demote to from the form's context menu.